# MessageBox string with variable name value dev c++

Tags: c++, messagebox

I im using dev c++ to create open dialog and i need to write in MessageBox error message "Unable to open file C:\test.txt" i try with this code:

```
MessageBox(hwnd, "Unable to open file "&(LPSTR)szFileName, "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
```

But it gives me error about char complains...how can i add string with variable value in messagebox?

char szFileName[MAX_PATH]; is defined with this and its value for this example is "test.txt"

How can i display this string+variable value(filename) in msgbox?

Comment: `("Unable to open file ' + std::string(szFileName)).c_str()` is the one liner.  Much better to make szFileName be a `std::string` though.

Comment: Also, you really ought to be writing Unicode apps these days.  In which case you need `(L"Unable to open file ) + std::wstring(szFilename)).c_str())` with `szFileName` being `wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH];`

Comment: Thanks Martin Bonner i use your solution and it works...